# ERROR:'AttributeError: can't set attribute' while using vaex

Tags: python, vaex

This is my code.Pretty straight forward.

```
import vaex    
vaex_df = vaex.from_pandas(df, copy_index=False)
vaex_df.export_hdf5('my_data.hdf5')
```

However i get the error.

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vaex\dataframe.py in
> _save_assign_expression(self, name, expression)    3306                 expression =
> vaex.utils.valid_expression(self.get_column_names(hidden=True),
> expression)    3307                 expression = Expression(self,
> expression)
> -> 3308             setattr(self, name, expression)    3309     3310     @_hidden
>
> AttributeError: can't set attribute

Also the same error when i try the following:

```
vaex_df = vx.from_csv('C83DD40F42D3_motions.csv', convert = True, chunk_size=100)
```

Comment: https://vaex.io/docs/api.html#vaex.from_pandas

Comment: pandas has no attribute from_csv. Please elaborate your answer more

Comment: Vaex may change a bit between versions.. would be useful to know which version you are running. Also, i believe it is recommended to know use vaex with anaconda, but either via miniconda or pip/pipenv environments.